# Add a server to an already running DRBD9 configuration

Tags: centos7, pacemaker, drbd

I am on CentOS7 and I have an existing two-cluster HA node running pacemaker (1.1.23-1.el7_9.1) and DRBD (kmod-drbd90-9.0.22-3.el7_9). The backing partition for the DRBD drive is LUKS encrypted. We are adding a third server to the stack, but after updating the configuration, the drbd drive on the new server does not connect.

## Status

The current status, as shown by the new box is:

```
[root@svr3]# drbdadm status
drbd0 role:Secondary
  disk:Inconsistent
  svr1 connection:Connecting
  svr2 connection:Connecting
```

From the primary, the status shows as:

```
[root@svr1]# drbdadm status
drbd0 role: Primary
  disk:UpToDate
  svr2 role:Secondary
    peer-disk:UpToDate
  svr3 connection:StandAlone
```

## DRBD Configuration

The current configuration for the `drbd0` resource is:

```
resource drbd0 {
  protocol C;
  device /dev/drbd0;
  disk /dev/sdb1;
  meta-disk internal;
  on svr1 {
    address 10.10.11.1:7789;
    node-id 1;
  }
  on svr2 {
    address 10.10.11.2:7789;
    node-id 2;
  }
  on svr3 {
    address 10.10.11.3:7789;
    node-id 3;
  }
  connection-mesh {
    hosts svr1 svr2 svr3;
  }
}
```

Prior to adding svr3, the configuration on svr1 and svr2 was as follows:

```
resource drbd0 {
  protocol C;
  device /dev/drbd0;
  disk /dev/sdb1;
  meta-disk internal;
  on svr1 {
    address 10.10.11.1:7789;
    node-id 1;
  }
  on svr2 {
    address 10.10.11.2:7789;
    node-id 2;
  }
  connection-mesh {
    hosts svr1 svr2;
  }
}
```

The DRBD disks were created with the following script on all boxes:

```
drbdadm create-md --force drbd0
drbdadm up drbd0
```

On the primary only, the following was also run to set up the disk:

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdb1 bs=128M count=10
drbdadm primary --force drbd0

cryptsetup -q --keyfile /path/to/keyfile luksFormat /dev/drbd0
cryptsetup --key-file /path/to/keyfile luksOpen /dev/drbd0 luks-drbd

mkfs.ext4 /dev/mapper/luks-drbd
```

## Pacemaker Configuration

The DRBD resources in pacemaker were configured with the following script. The PCS resource hasn't changed, as it was originally set up to allow for a future third node.

```
pcs resource create drbd0_data ocf:linbit:drbd drbd_resource=drbd0
pcs resource master drbd0_clone drbd0_data \
  master-max=1 master-node-max=1 clone-max=3 clone-node-max=1 \
  notify=true
pcs resource create drbd0_luks ocf:vendor:luks \
  --group=drbd_resources
pcs resource create drbd0_fs ocf:heartbeat:Filesystem \
  device=/dev/mapper/luks-drbd directory=/mnt/data fstype=ext4 \
  --group=drbd_resources

pcs constraint order promote drbd0_data then start drbd_resources
pcs constraint colocation add drbd_resources \
  with drbd0_clone INFINTITY with-rsc-role=Master
pcs constraint order drbd0_luks then drbd0_fs
```

(The `drbd0_luks` resource is a custom resource we provide that basically runs `cryptsetup luksOpen|luksClose` on the LUKS partition as appropriate).

The pacemaker status shows the following:

```
Online: [ svr1 svr2 svr3 ]

Active resources:

 Master/Slave Set: drbd0_clone [drbd0_data]
     Masters: [ svr1 ]
     Slaves: [ svr2 svr3 ]
 Resource Group: drbd_resources
     drbd0_luks (ocf::vendor::luks):     Started svr1
     drbd0_fs   (ocf::heartbeat::Filesystem):    Started svr1
```

## Attempts to Connect

I've tried various iterations of the following process:

```
[root@svr1]# drbdadm disconnect drbd0

[root@svr2]# drbdadm disconnect drbd0

[root@svr3]# drbdadm disconnect drbd0
[root@svr3]# drbdadm connect --discard-my-data drbd0

[root@svr1]# drbdadm connect drbd0
drbd0: Failure: (162) Invalid configuration request
Command 'drbdsetup connect drbd0 3' terminated with exit code 10

[root@svr2]# drbdadm connect drbd0
drbd0: Failure: (162) Invalid configuration request
Command 'drbdsetup connect drbd0 3' terminated with exit code 10
```

After this, the output of `drbdadm status` is as shown at the top of the post. I get the same error if I attempt to run `drbdadm adjust drbd0` on svr1 or svr2.

If I attempt to run `drbdadm down drbd0` while the `drbd0_luks` resource is enabled, I get the following:

```
[root@svr1]# drbdadm down drbd0
drbd0: State change failed: (-12) Device is held open by someone
additional info from kernel:
/dev/drbd0 opened by cryptsetup (pid 11777) at 2021-11-01 16:50:51
Command 'drbdsetup down drbd0' terminated with exit code 11
```

If I disabled the `drbd0_luks` resource, I can run `drbdadm down drbd0`, but the `adjust` command fails with the following:

```
[root@svr1]# drbdadm adjust drbd0
0: Failure: (162) Invalid configuration request
Command 'drbdsetup attach 0 /dev/sdb1 /dev/sdb1 internal' terminated with exit code 10
```

so I am assuming that I at least need that much up and running. At this point I'm just grasping for straws, but I'm not quite sure what the next correct straw is to reach for.

Comment: You should see more information in the logs, but my gut says you probably don't have room for the additional (3rd node's) metadata. When you first created the metadata (on 2 nodes), you could have passed `create-md` the `--max-peers=3` flag to reserve some extra bitmap slots. With the LUKS volume and FS already created, the metadata expansion would have to overwrite the end of the FS. Please post anything from the logs while running `drbdadm up` / `drbdadm down` and that should provide more information.

Comment: Based on what I've seen, and coupled with reading (and finally understanding) this blog: https://www.neteye-blog.com/2020/04/adding-node-to-drbd-device-with-wrong-max-peers/ I think that that's exactly the situation we're in. Unfortunately, the way these were built initially it's not looking possible for us to extend that backing partition, so I'm guessing we'll have a rebuild in our future as the least painful option.

Comment: You could also convert to external meta-data (assuming you have some other small block device you can use for it), but it would require `umount` and `down` on the DRBD devices.